# Phonegap downloading from PHP file

Tags: php, android, cordova

I'm having a PhoneGap application that downloads a file from my server. The problem is that if I point phonegap FileTransfer.download uri directly to the file, the file can be downloaded. But, if I point the URI of FileTransfer.download to a download.php file that has the following:

```
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

My phonegap application downloads the file. But it only has 1 byte of data and cannot download the content of my file ( It's a MP3 file ).

Can someone let me know why this happens? I need to use the download.php file because I'm sending a hash to verify the user credentials before allowing the file to be downloaded.

I've been working around a few hours on this and couldn't find a solution. Is there a proble m with the fileTransfer.download? Should I make additional settings to it?

Comment: does the php script works if you run it in your browser. Does it give you a file?

Comment: Sure. the PHP script works perfectly. It sends me back the file as an MP3 and file has it's integrity. Also, this worked in my Android native application. But not on PhoneGap fileTransfer.

Comment: forgot to mention that there is a slight delay before the file is served. Around 2-4 seconds at most, and sometimes can go around 20-30 seconds if the file needs to be created again.

Comment: what happens if you point a browser directly at this download.php? do you have display_errors/error_reporting enabled to see if something's blowing up in php?

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears correct, but here is another implementation that you could try.

```
header("Content-Type: " . mime_content_type($file));
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

$file_name = pathinfo($file);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name['basename'] . "\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

if ($fp=fopen($file, "r")){ 
    fpassthru($fp);
}
```

Comment: Did your changes. The file can be downloaded in a web browser. But the fileTransfer doesn't want to download it.

Comment: @roshkattu what error codes do you get ... `fileTransfer.download(
    url,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
);
`

Answer (score 0):

Your content-type header appears incorrect.

Try changing the header like this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
```

Comment: will do the changes now and check them.

Comment: I still get the same result. Nothing changes. The file can be downloaded, but not as it should.